# prioritize within city response for address using maps.googleapis

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api

As I am typing autocomplete address using http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?sensor=false&address=******  I would like to prioritize within that city any address that begins with the following name .For ex: if I type mount and priority is California then it should give back Mountain view as the recommendation answer.How do I do that .I really appreciate any help.PLease let me know with respect to the above api call.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Viewports

The short of it is that you can add a 'bounds' parameter that specifies lat-lng points to hint to the geocoder that you wish to look within a particular area. An example from that page is: 
    http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Winnetka&bounds=34.172684,-118.604794|34.236144,-118.500938&sensor=false

Comment: Thanks for looking into it .Can I set locality as bounds like Los Angeles?

Comment: even by doing that I cannot get the required location in 3 letters .

Comment: or a suggestion with 3 letters

Comment: How do I use administrator:area as city name ?